# Passing value from select form with Ajax not working

Tags: ajax

Im trying to pass a variable from a select form, but cant get it to work - whats the correct way to do this?

Console is now giving me object error: `statusText: "parsererror"`

**Update:**

Changed the json_encode and updated the script. I know get the corretc value, but the if/else statement isnt firing.

**Form**

```
<select id="dropdown_shop_order_language" name="wcml_shop_order_language">                  
<option value="nl">Nederlands</option>
<option value="en" selected="selected">Engels</option>
<option value="de">Duits</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
   jQuery('#dropdown_shop_order_language').on('change', function(){

      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
          data: {
              'action':'my_action',            
               'dropdown_shop_order_language': $('#dropdown_shop_order_language').val() 
 
          },
          success:function(data) {      
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(errorThrown){
              console.log(errorThrown);
          }
      });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
function my_enque_action( $hook ) {
global $post;
     $postid = $post->ID; 
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {    
        
        if( get_post_type( $postid ) === 'shop_order' ) {  
         wp_enqueue_script( 'lang_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/language.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_action', 10, 1 );

function my_action( ) {
 $dropdown_shop_order_language = $_POST['dropdown_shop_order_language'];
        
        if ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'nl' ) {

        } elseif ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'de' ) {
    
        } elseif ( $dropdown_shop_order_language == 'en' ) {
        
        }    
 
 echo json_encode($dropdown_shop_order_language);
   wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the ajax actions, there are two, one for logged in users and one for not logged in users.
Going by your action you will need to add the following actions.

```php
// this one for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');

// this one for not logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Comment: Thank you, feel a bit stupid now. I accidentally deleted them in one of the versions I was trying, put them back and I dont get an error for the ajax script now. I still get the error with the popup so something still not right.

Comment: @Jerry Thats because alert doesn't know out to output objects, try using `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Now I see this: statusText: "parsererror"

Comment: @Jerry take a look at the ajax property for post, instead of `method: 'post'`, you have `type: 'post'`

Comment: thank you, update my question. I still get the parse error though.

Comment: @Jerry you are missing a `;` on this line `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_action', 10, 1 )`, the ajax is fine, copy pasted it and it works as expected, add the missing `;` and you should be fine =].

Comment: Thanks, I do have this in my script ,just missed it when I copied to the question - Not sure why but I still het the error. All looks fine to me as well.

Comment: Try commenting this line `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_action', 10, 1 );`, I suspect that `$post->ID` causes this, if I rememebr correctly hooking into `admin_enqueue_scripts` and using `global $post` will not have $post, because $post is not declared in admin dashboard

Comment: Commented the line but didnt help - I didnt get the console log when doing this.

Comment: @Jerry well going by the code you provided that isn't much to do, the code looks fine and after testing it myself I know it should work. Try enabling wp_debug and wp_debug_log, see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information, after debug is enabled run the ajax again and check for errors.

Comment: Hmm strange. I just get the error and not the sucess log.

Comment: I changed the script and the json_encode and now I see the right variable in console! I van not get the if/else statement to fire accordingly though